# Tomcat with JAVA_OPTS fail to start

Tags: tomcat, java-opts

this is the memory i have on my server (from webmin page) :

Operating system    Debian Linux 7
Webmin version  1.760
Kernel and CPU  Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae on i686
Processor information   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz, 2 cores
Real memory     698.57 MB used, 7.92 GB total
Virtual memory  0 bytes used, 2.07 GB total
Local disk space    5.51 GB used, 47.17 GB total

and this is the JAVA_OPTS that i have into the startup script of tomcat :

JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC";

so i have a server with 8Gb RAM, but if I change the -Xmx2048m parameter to a larger value (for example 3072m) tomcat fails to start with a "not enough memory.."

I cannot understand why..

Comment: 32-bit JVM, perhaps? Edit: actually, it seems to be 32-bit OS (i686)

Comment: In general, 32-bit application can't allocate more than 4G of RAM (it typically is even less than that, depending on operating system and other conditions).

Comment: Update: In theory, any 32-bit application can't allocate more than 4G of RAM. It is typically less than that, depending on operating system and other conditions (e.g. on 32-bit Windows, the maximum JVM heap size can't be more than some 1.6G). I'm not sure about 32-bit Debian limitations, it's something you might want to find out. Also keep in mind that JVM does not allocate only the heap, it needs some memory e.g. for permgen (seems 256M in your case), the JVM itself and so on.

Comment: thank you david.. it seems it's a 32-bit limitation : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit